# FirstOrDefault in DbSet slow using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, expression, dbset

I have this Linq expression (FirstOrDefault) and it's very slow.
Options is an DbSet

```
 DbOption dbo = ctx.Options.FirstOrDefault(o =>
                        o.SynN == oLoaded.SynN &&
                        o.OwnerId == oLoaded.OwnerId &&
                        o.Context == oLoaded.Context);
```

There is a way faster to find my options? I see with "Expression", but how can I convert this Linq code in Expression? I have never used it.

Thanks for the support

Comment: The expression looks suspicious. Why are you comparing the same property? `o.SynN == o.SynN` and `o.Context == o.Context`?

Comment: You can reduce the expression to `.FirstOrDefault(o => o.OwnerId == o.Id)` - the rest is obsolete.

Comment: Do you have a composite index on SynN, OwnerId, and Context?

Comment: No, I have change my code. I have simplify the code for the post in a wrong mode. Sorry. Now It's ok

Comment: Based on the code, really all that can be said is: no, there's no faster way. FYI, `(o => ...)` *is* an expression.

Comment: Post your *table* schema and indexes. EF translates LINQ queries to SQL. What you posted will be translated to `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Options where SynN=@param1 AND OwnerID=@param2 and Context=@param3)`. Query performance depends on the table indexes and statistics. Without the proper indexes the database will have to scan the entire table to find matches.

Comment: You should only load the data you need too. If you only need a specific option value, use `Select(o=>o.Value)` to generate `SELECT TOP 1 Value` instead of `SELECT TOP 1 *`. This may not be that significant when loading a single small row, but can cause significant delays if you load a wide table with lots of `varchar(max)` or `varbinary(max)` fields.

Answer (score 1):

In case of too many records, you can create a index to improve the performance of your query against the database

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Options_SynN_OwnerId_Context] ON [dbo].[Options]
(
    [SynN] ASC,
    [OwnerId] ASC,
    [Context] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```